# Get name of an image in java

Tags: java, image, url

Is it possible to get the name of an image in java. The image source is a url.

For eg. "http://172.16.2.42/apache_pb.png"

I need the output "apache_pb.png"

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "http://172.16.2.42/apache_pb.png";
int index = s.lastIndexOf('/');

String name = s.substring(index+1);
System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this helper method from the `URL` class:

```
String file = new URL("http://172.16.2.42/apache_pb.png").getPath();
```

Comment: @Dennis : Is it possible to get the name from bufferedImage response or anything like that. Because what I need is if the url is not a valid one, the program will fetch a default image. I need to check the response of which image I get.

Answer (score 1):

Would [URL#getFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29) do this for you?